# Python calculating Catalan Numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, catalan

I have code which is calculating catalan numbers with method of Binominal Coefficients.

```
def BinominalCoefficient(n,k):
    res = 1;
    if (k > n - k):
        k = n - k
    for i in range(k):
        res *= (n - i)
        res /= (i + 1)
    return res
def CatalanNumbers(n):
   c = BinominalCoefficient(2*n, n)
   return (c//(n+1))
print (CatalanNumbers(510))
```

I have a "nan" result when i try to calculate Catalan number which n is more than 510. Why this is happening? And how can i solve it?

Comment: You get `nan` because `BinominalCoefficient(1022, 511)` returns `inf`.

Comment: Are you using Python 3? If so use integer division `//` to avoid floats (you don't need them for this calculation anyway).

Comment: What python version are you using? I get correct results in both python 2.6.6 as well as python 3.4.3

Comment: I am using Python 3.4.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you're using Python 3.

Your `res /= (i + 1)` should be `res //= (i + 1)` to force integer arithmetic:

```
def BinominalCoefficient(n,k):
    res = 1
    if (k > n - k):
        k = n - k
    for i in range(k):
        res *= (n - i)
        res //= (i + 1)
    return res
def CatalanNumbers(n):
   c = BinominalCoefficient(2*n, n)
   return (c//(n+1))
print (CatalanNumbers(511))
```

returns

```
2190251491739477424254235019785597839694676372955883183976582551028726151813997871354391075304454574949251922785248583970189394756782256529178824038918189668852236486561863197470752363343641524451529091938039960955474280081989297135147411990495428867310575974835605457151854594468879961981363032236839645
```

You get `nan` because the divison /= in Python 3 returns a float which overflows to `inf`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [xnx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459931/9297144), note that starting `Python 3.8`, with the addition of [`math.comb`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html?highlight=comb#math.comb) (binomial coefficient) in the standard library, we can also calculate Catalan numbers as such:

```
import math

def catalan(n):
  return math.comb(2*n, n) / (n+1)

catalan(511) # 2.1902514917394773e+303
```

Comment: Notice that this solution is bounded by the float bounds. The maximal Catalan number that can be calculated this way is catalan(519), for catalan(520) you'll get OverflowError